# Как быстро проверить конфиги впн?

Tags: openvpn, wireguard

По работе меняю на серверах ubuntu конфигурационные файлы клиента (openVPN и wireguard)
Соответственно имею много файлов, периодически ВПН не поднимается по причине, умершей VPS.

Как можно проверить быстро файлы ибо файлов много, выданы на месяц и к концу месяца их становится больше мертвых, чем выживших.

По моему скромному мнению должна быть команда, проверяющая это, но пока не могу найти.

Comment: OpenVPN и WireGuard не имеют никакого отношения друг к другу, так что вопрос должен быть поделён как минимум на два отдельных

Comment: Ну и не очень понятно, что конкретно вы хотите проверить - корректность файлов совсем не обязательно означает, что подключение к vpn будет успешным

Comment: да, Вы правы, стоило разделить

Comment: файлы все корректны и работают на начало месяца, в конце месяца подкидываю файл и начинается лотерея, так как хочется автоматизировать процесс, то и возник вопрос.